# Replacing, filtering an URL via .htaccess or PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, replace, filtering, mod-rewrite

Looking for solution of replacing/filtering URL's via .htaccess or PHP:

`www.domain.com/?site=FilteringSite.com`

should go to:

`www.domain.com`

I have try:

```
#SEO Friendly 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 http://www.domain.com/?site=FilteringSite.com http://www.domain.com
```

and seems not to work.

The htaccess file

```
#### mod_rewrite in use
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: From what it looks like based on what you have, you are trying to redirect parameters that are being sent to your domain, which `301` status would be useless for - it's the same exact page.

Comment: ***** I want to block specific words or domains in the URL after ?site=... However, I want to keep the usage of the /?site=... for appropriate use URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure a `301 Redirect` won't work on the query string, but you can try a PHP solution like:

```
<?php

$badDomains = array("filtersite.com", "filteringsite.com");

if(in_array(strtolower($_GET['site']), $badDomains)) {
    header("Location: http://mydomain.com", true, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Though, I do believe the redirect only applies to everything before the `?`. ^^

Comment: well, the following code is not the smocking gun: 

<?
//PHP URL Filtering
$badDomains = array("69.com", "69.com/");

if(in_array(str2lower($_GET['site']), $badDomains)) {
    header("Location: http://www.mp7.org", true, 301);
    exit;
}
?>


*** Below is the url I want to block

http://www.mp7.org/?site=69.com

Comment: Never said you should accept it if it doesn't work for you - however, it was something to get you started.  Nowhere in the question do you specify how the list is created, only a way in which to accomplish what you are looking for in `.htaccess` or `php`.  It is assumed that the code won't work straight off the bat if you don't store the domains in an array, but can be adapted to fit your needs - which is the implication in any `code` answer where specific code in that language was not demonstrated in the question.

Comment: To your edit, you've added characters in there that aren't in my code, a `;` after the `"Location: mp7.org";` and `str2lower` (which I did fix in my edit to `strtolower`.) ^^  Also, it is noted that 301 redirects won't affect the `query string` of a page, only the actual location. With the code you put in, you should get a parser error, and a call to an undefined function. =]

Comment: Thanks. The edited code did the work. You can NO longer access: http://www.mp7.org/?site=69.com

Comment: Well, the slashes compromises the URL even the 69.com is listed under bad domains $badDomains = array("69.com", "69.com/"); See: http://www.mp7.org/?site=69.com\\\\\\\\

Comment: You can always `trim($_GET['site'], '\\/ ');` before the check to remove slashes and spaces from the ends, or you can do a `foreach` for the `$badDomains` array and check `strpos` of it to the current value.

Comment: Can you pls update the current value to remove slashes with the foreach for the $badDomains? Thanks